# Trouble understanding Javascript closure example

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I understand most of what closures are, but then this example got me quite confused. I will post two code examples: the first one will be the original quote where they explain the workings of closure and the second will be code where I added something, but it did not give me the results I expected.

This is the explanation they give:

> This final example shows that each call creates a separate closure for
>   the local variables. There is not a single closure per function
>   declaration. There is a closure for each call to a function.

The actual code:

```
function newClosure(someNum, someRef) {
    // Local variables that end up within closure
    var num = someNum;
    var anArray = [1,2,3];
    var ref = someRef;
    return function(x) {
        num += x;
        anArray.push(num);
        console.log('num: ' + num +
            '; anArray: ' + anArray.toString() +
            '; ref.someVar: ' + ref.someVar + ';');
      }
}
obj = {someVar: 4};
fn1 = newClosure(4, obj);
fn2 = newClosure(5, obj);
fn1(1); // num: 5; anArray: 1,2,3,5; ref.someVar: 4;
fn2(1); // num: 6; anArray: 1,2,3,6; ref.someVar: 4;
obj.someVar++;
fn1(2); // num: 7; anArray: 1,2,3,5,7; ref.someVar: 5;
fn2(2); // num: 8; anArray: 1,2,3,6,8; ref.someVar: 5;
```

Now, I don't understand why obj.someVar++ changes the result in the last two lines and the following addition of num++ doesn't change the last two num results to 8 and 9 instead of 7 and 8. What's the difference?

```
function newClosure(someNum, someRef) {
    // Local variables that end up within closure
    var num = someNum;
    var anArray = [1,2,3];
    var ref = someRef;
    return function(x) {
        num += x;
        anArray.push(num);
        console.log('num: ' + num +
            '; anArray: ' + anArray.toString() +
            '; ref.someVar: ' + ref.someVar + ';');
      }
}
num = 4
obj = {someVar: 4};
fn1 = newClosure(num, obj);
fn2 = newClosure(num+1, obj);
fn1(1); // num: 5; anArray: 1,2,3,5; ref.someVar: 4;
fn2(1); // num: 6; anArray: 1,2,3,6; ref.someVar: 4;
num++
obj.someVar++;
fn1(2); // num: 7; anArray: 1,2,3,5,7; ref.someVar: 5;
fn2(2); // num: 8; anArray: 1,2,3,6,8; ref.someVar: 5;
```

Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *Why does `obj.someVar++` change the result in the last two lines?*

   Because `ref` in the function is a reference to the object. You changed `obj.someVar`, and thus the following logs reflect that change.
2. *Why does the following addition of num++ not change the last two num results to 8 and 9 instead of 7 and 8?*

   The `num` variable is not the same as the one outside since you used the keyword `var`. JavaScript is function-scoped and they are referring to different values.

---

I can see where the confusion comes from. You tried to pass `someNum` and `someRef` in and did the "same" operation (increment) on them but you got different behaviors.

One thing that you have to realize is that the value of `num` is a primitive value `4`, and the value of `obj` is a reference (similar to a pointer in C). Think of a reference as a number that indicates memory addresses (but not exactly a number). When you pass them into the function, the values are copied:

- For `num`, the value `4` is copied.
- For `obj`, the value, in this case, the reference, is copied.

Since copying the reference does not create a new object, when you change the value `obj.someVar` outside the function, the changes will reflect in the function since it's still referring to the same object.

Comment: Amazing, I understand it now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm really starting to enjoy Javascript and all its little details. Thanks again for the response.